# failure to submit a question

Tags: support, asking-questions

I have tried to submit the following question on the math exchange:

---

I need to prove that:

$$ 27x^2 < x^{\log_3x} $$

can any one please explain how to solve this type of equation?
I have no idea what to do or what to search for.

---

site keeps telling me it doesn't qualify the question standard, please help.

Comment: Your question might be too short. By the way, your inequality fails for $x=1$.

Answer (score 7):

There is a black box containing some sort of filter that automatically takes out some questions. I would recommend expanding the question just a bit - say where it came from and what your thoughts are (always good anyway), and it is likely that the black box will stop being fickle.